# Nginx write logs to the old file after running logrotate

Tags: nginx, logrotate

The logrotate config is:

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/nginx:

/data/logs/nginx/*.log
{
daily
dateext
dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
rotate 30
missingok
create
notifempty
sharedscripts
postrotate
        [ ! -f /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
endscript
}
```

But nginx write logs to the access.log.2016-05-15, not access.log

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www  root    0 May 14 03:46 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www  root  47M May 16 10:26 access.log.2016-05-15
```

How should I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com ?

Comment: Thanks, I posted it, but no response. :(

Comment: `/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid` is an unusual place for pid file. Are you sure that it's there and has actual data? Have you tried to send `USR1` to `nginx` processes manually?

Comment: I found this message in nginx errror log: "2016/05/16 19:34:04 [emerg] 11797#0: open() "/data/logs/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)", but ./sbin/nginx -t is OK, and I changed the file to 755, still has this error, realy werid.

Comment: OK, I figured out, It's the permission issue. I should also add "x" permission to the parent directory. Thanks man.